# Using talloc in an embedded project

Tags: c, compiler-errors, embedded

I would like to be able to use [talloc](http://talloc.samba.org/talloc/doc/html/index.html) in an embedded project I am working on, but have been unable to determine how I go about incorporating it into my development environment. The environment in question is a vendor-supplied Windows IDE that uses ARM GCC 4.4.1, and I am using it to target an ARM7 device.

I have gotten to the stage where the compiler is complaining about conflicting types:

```
In file included from .\talloc-2.0.8\talloc.c:33:
.\talloc-2.0.8\lib\replace/replace.h:626: error: conflicting types for 'ptrdiff_t'
c:\program files (x86)\cypress\psoc creator\2.2\psoc creator\import\gnu_cs\arm\4.4.1\bin\../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.4.1/include/stddef.h:149: note: previous declaration of 'ptrdiff_t' was here
.\talloc-2.0.8\lib\replace/replace.h:848: error: conflicting types for 'useconds_t'
c:\program files (x86)\cypress\psoc creator\2.2\psoc creator\import\gnu_cs\arm\4.4.1\bin\../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.4.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/include/sys/types.h:253: note: previous declaration of 'useconds_t' was here
.\talloc-2.0.8\talloc.c:123: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'uint8_t'
```

I noticed that replace.h tries to include a file called config.h that does not exist in the talloc source tree - a problem I got around by creating a blank file by that name. Is the idea to use config.h to inform talloc what functions are already defined by the system? Is this just a matter of using the `#define` directive to prevent replace.h from trying to replace existing types?

Given that this is the first time I have attempted to use code that I did not write myself in a project, I am somewhat confused as to how to go about reconciling these conflicts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`config.h` should be generated automatically. For tmalloc, it's done by [waf](http://code.google.com/p/waf/) (python-based build system).

```
$ python ./buildtools/bin/waf configure
Checking for program gcc or cc           : /usr/lib/ccache/gcc 
Checking for program cpp                 : /usr/bin/cpp 
Checking for program ar                  : /usr/bin/ar 
Checking for program ranlib              : /usr/bin/ranlib 
Checking for gcc                         : ok  
Checking for program git                 : /usr/bin/git 
Check for -MD                            : yes 
....
$ python ./buildtools/bin/waf build
.....
```

Comment: Thank you for that. It seems the first thing I need to do is go and learn how to use python.

Comment: Having read some of the python files that are part of the talloc source distribution, I am concerned that it may not be possible to use waf under Windows to generate the necessary `config.h` file. Everything seems specifically set up for linux, which is hardly surprising. Has anyone ever done this under Windows?

Comment: I am getting error for: `Checking uname version type              : not found
Checking for header stdio.h              : no`. see the [screenshot](http://snag.gy/2Intu.jpg)